# Type "100%" is not assignable to type number in kendo-grid-column

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In the columns of the grid, I want to set the width as 100%.

```
<kendo-grid-column 
   field="id"
   title="id"
   [width]="'100%'">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

But I hover over the code, it shows:

> **Type "100%" is not assignable to type number**

Comment: [Kendo UI Grid Column width option only takes in a number (in pixels)](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/#toc-width).

Comment: I used the percent, it seems works but it just creates noise when hover it.

Comment: Why would you need to set width 100% to a column?

Comment: It may be used in desktop or mobile device so I don't want the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `strictTemplates: true` has been specified in `angularCompilerOptions` under `tsconfig.json`.

If you look at the definition file (`column-base.d.ts`), you can see that the property `width` has been assigned to be of type `number`. As such, if you were to feed anything but something of type `number`, this will cause a warning.

The reason you are still able to execute `100%` without a problem is because Javascript understands what you are trying to do and is able to parse the width as "full screen".

You can choose to modify the `column-base.d.ts` file to make the width as following:
`width: number | string;`.